# Problem with Dropout version Google Colab

Tags: tensorflow, keras, google-colaboratory, dropout

I am trying to add a dropout layer and I get this warning

```
WARNING:tensorflow:From /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py:3445: calling dropout (from tensorflow.python.ops.nn_ops) with keep_prob is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Please use `rate` instead of `keep_prob`. Rate should be set to `rate = 1 - keep_prob`.
```

I do not understand if I am using rate or keep_prob.
My implementation in the dropout layer is as follows:

```
x = Dropout(rate=0.20)(x)
```

I import keras with tensorflow backend. 
The versions are:

Keras                    2.2.4

tensorflow               1.13.1

How can I check if that 0.20 is used as rate or keep_prob?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is giving you a warning to not use keep_prob. But since you are using rate it will be the rate, not keep_prob. It is a confusing warning. To check it put it to 1, if it learns then it is keep_prob, if it doesn't it is drop out rate!

Comment: It specifically tells to USE rate. This warning is confusing, indeed.

Answer (score 1):

According to keras documentation

```
keras.layers.Dropout(rate, noise_shape=None, seed=None)
```

So, use

```
x = Dropout(0.20)(x)
```

here 0.20 will be the rate.